# a split exact sequence of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose G has a cyclic normal subgroup $\langle a\rangle$ of order $m$ and prime power index $s$ such that $m$ and $s$ are relatively prime. Then the following exact sequence splits:

> $$1 \longrightarrow  \langle a\rangle \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow G/\langle a\rangle \longrightarrow 1$$

Such group G is called a hyperelementary group.

> **Question:**  How to define a homomorphism  $G/\langle a\rangle \rightarrow G$ to make the above sequence split ?

Comment: Use Sylow's theorem.

Comment: Yes. And the splitting works for all normal subgroups of $p$-power index which have order prime to $p$, whether they are cyclic or not. Rather deeper is the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem, which says that a normal subgroup whose order and index are relatively prime is complemented.